# Two index formulation for capacitated vehicle routing problem

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, integer-programming

I'm trying to model the capacitated vehicle routing problem with two index in the case of two fleets with respective capacity $q_1$ and $q_2$. I tried several versions for many months and now I have a problem in modeling the case
$$
q_2 < d_i,
$$
where $d_i$ is demand of the customer $i$. Here is the $m$ model:
$$
\min\sum_{\substack{i\in N\\ j\in N}}[c_1(i,j)\cdot x_1(i,j)+c_2(i,j)\cdot x_2(i,j)],
$$
subject to the constraints
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{j∈C} x_1(0,j) &\le n\\
\sum_{j∈C} x_2(0,j) &\le m\\
\sum_{i∈C} x_1(i,0) &\le n\\
\sum_{ji∈C} x_2(i,0) &\le m\\
\sum_{i∈C} x_1(i,j) &+ x2(i,j) =1\quad\forall j\in C\\
\sum_{i∈N} x_1(i,j) &−x_1(j,i) =0\quad \forall j\in C\\
\sum_{i∈C} x_2(i,j) &−x_2(j,i) =0\quad\forall j\in C\\
y(j) \le y(i) &−d_j\cdot(x_1(i,j)+x_2(i,j))+M\cdot(1−(x_1(i,j)+x_2(i,j))\quad\forall i,j\in C\\
0 \le y(i) \le &\max(q_1,q_2)−d_i\quad \forall i\in C
\end{split}
$$
Does anyone can help in modelling this case? Thank you

Comment: Cross-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/11487/vehicle-routing-problem-with-two-fleets

Comment: Thank you Daniele Tampieri for editing my post. I post it here because I need more help to solve my problem. I'm still having issues with my model.